# GIZA++' s command "plain2snt.out" does nothing in CYGWIN

Tags: nlp, machine-translation, giza++

I am trying to use GIZA++ for word alignment using CYGWIN. I compiled GIZA++ with the MAKE command and gained files need for further processing: Giza++.exe, mkcls.exe, snt2cooc.out, plain2snt.out. However, when I execute:

```
User@User-PC /home/giza-pp-master/giza++-v2
$ ./plain2snt.out file1.txt file2.txt
```

there are no .vcb and .snt files created. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First create two files i.e. "file1.txt" and "file2.txt" [as you mentioned in the command i.e. ./plain2snt.out file1.txt file2.txt] and save both the files in giza++-v2 folder [i.e. your working folder as shown in your comment].